# System checks for disk drive error every time it boots

Tags: ubuntu-13.10

System checks for disk drive error every time it boots every time when it's boot
how to fix it thanx for any help in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps:

1. Boot from the install CD/DVD and go into rescue mode.
2. Keep the error partition unmounted.
3. Do fsck on the partition to fix errors it detects.
4. Reboot from the ordinary partition.

Do not neglect the errors your system reports.